# Account access mamagement in Adwords API (invite user into an account)

Tags: google-ads-api

I cant find how to process this action via API call?
http://prntscr.com/cw9ntm - this is what I am doing in web.

I have an account, and I want to invite another user into this account knowing his email?
I expect API-call like

```
$myAuthorizedUser->invite($otherUserEmail, $accessLevel)
```